# Why different column width in table

Tags: tables, multicol

I am getting different column width in table and i am not able to correct this. The row with multiple columns in last (with text member) has uneven width. 
Please help.

Here is a sample code.

```
\begin{table*}[h!]
\centering
 \vspace{0.5em}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\small \textbf{Progress of the Candidate:}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}      {\small \textbf{Excellent/Good/Satisfactory/Unsatisfactory}} \\[1ex] \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\small \textbf{Remarks:}}                         \\[10ex] \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{}\\[3em]
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{$\overline{\strut \small \textbf{Signature(s) \& Names(s) of  Guide(s)}}$ } & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\hspace{12em}\small \textbf{Date}}   \\[0.5em] \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{}\\[3em] \hline
\small \textbf{Member 1}       &  \small  \textbf{Member 2}      &    \small           \textbf{Member 3}       &  \small  \textbf{Member 4}        \\ 
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\small \textbf{Signature \& Names of DC Members}} \\ \hline                         
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a `tabularx` solution, since the first row has contents that are over the length of 4 columns, causing the mis-alignment of the OP. Basically the X column is used to adjust the width automatically and it has a style defined by `newcolumntype` command

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[h!]
\centering
 \vspace{0.5em}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{\small \textbf{Progress of the Candidate:}} &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}      {\small \textbf{Excellent/Good/Satisfactory/Unsatisfactory}} 
\\[1ex] \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\small \textbf{Remarks:}}   \\[10ex] \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{}\\[3em]
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{$\overline{\strut \small \textbf{Signature(s) \& Names(s) of  Guide(s)}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\hfill \small \textbf{Date}}   \\[0.5em] \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{}\\[3em]    \hline
\small  \textbf{Member 1}  & 
\small  \textbf{Member 2}  &  
\small  \textbf{Member 3}  & 
\small  \textbf{Member 4}        \\ 
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\small \textbf{Signature \& Names of DC Members}} \\ \hline                         
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[h!]
\centering
 \vspace{0.5em}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|C{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{\small \textbf{Progress of the Candidate:}} &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}      {\small \textbf{Excellent/Good/Satisfactory/Unsatisfactory}}
\\[1ex] \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\small \textbf{Remarks:}}   \\[10ex] \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{}\\[3em]
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{$\overline{\strut\text{\small \textbf{Signature(s) \& Names(s) of  Guide(s)}}}$} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\hfill \small \textbf{Date}}   \\[0.5em] \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{}\\[3em]    \hline
\small  \textbf{Member 1}  &
\small  \textbf{Member 2}  &
\small  \textbf{Member 3}  &
\small  \textbf{Member 4}        \\
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\small \textbf{Signature \& Names of DC Members}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that `small` is invalid in math mode. Hence I used `\text` macro from `amsmath` package.